# Translation custom function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, translation, plpgsql

I'm trying to make a custom function in PostgreSQL9.5 that takes a string and translates it into another language.
The particular thing about the strings i am trying to translate is that they are just a list of elements, so they are not required to make grammatical sense at all.

An example translation would be the following:

```
normal_string                translated_string
apple                        manzana
banana                       banano
tiger                        tigre
elephant | monkey | apple    elefante | mico | manzana  
the elephant ate a banana    the elefante ate a banano
```

I have already advanced a bit and found a way to do this, here is the function I have created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION translate_en_es(to_translate character varying)
RETURNS character varying AS $result$
declare
    result character varying;
BEGIN
SELECT
case when to_translate like 'apple' then replace(to_translate,'apple','manzana')
when to_translate like 'elephant' then replace(to_translate,'elephant','elefante')
...
...


else to_translate end::character varying
      into result;
RETURN result;
END;
$result$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As you can see the problem is that this function only works for one translation.

I was ok with using this function multiple times to replace multiple elements and obtain my desired result, but I am sure there is a better way to do this.

The workaround I was proposing is for example:

```
select translate_en_es(translate_en_es('apple | banana'))
```

How can I do it so that it will not be necessary to add as many functions as elements in the string?

Comment: Why not store the list of words (and their translations) in a table? It would then take a simple `select` to find the right translation.

Comment: i would have to make all possible combinations including those of multiple words like the fourth row in the example table

Comment: It still possible to make it work with a table, even with that requirement.

Comment: I modified the table example just in case it was not clear enough, a table cannot work since i would need to join in specific parts of the string and I cannot know that for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first impression is that you need a dictionary in the form of a table:

```
create table dictionary (id serial primary key, english text, spanish text);
insert into dictionary (english, spanish) values
('apple', 'manzana'),
('banana', 'banano'),
('tiger', 'tigre'),
('monkey', 'mico');
```

For a given english sentence the query searches the table and returns the found spanish words.

```
select english, spanish
from dictionary
join (
    select regexp_split_to_table('the monkey ate a banana', '\W+') word
    ) words
on word = english;

 english | spanish 
---------+---------
 banana  | banano
 monkey  | mico
(2 rows)
```

Note, we had to split the sentence into words (see the function [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)).

Use the above query in the function:

```
create or replace function english_to_spanish (sentence text)
returns text language plpgsql as $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select english, spanish
        from dictionary
        join (
            select regexp_split_to_table(sentence, '\W+') word
            ) words
        on word = english
    loop
        sentence:= replace(sentence, r.english, r.spanish);
    end loop;
    return sentence;
end $$;

select english_to_spanish ('the monkey ate a banana');

  english_to_spanish   
-----------------------
 the mico ate a banano
(1 row)
```